# Problem with route when deploying Symfony 4 application

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4, virtualhost

My application work on local environment, I deploy on VPS server, manage by me, source is deployed by Git with SSH.

Website: http://jw-motorsport.fr/

You can see that navigation doesn't work, I have already do work website into webserver, but with URL http://jw-motorsport.fr/public, its not convenient, so I decide to manage my virtual host for define the entry-point http://jw-motorsport.fr, and now, route doesn't work -_-'

I don't see any errors on my logs. (HTTP log)

This problem block me since many weeks, I try many issues, but I don't remember all I do for that^

My routes.yaml:

```
Index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::accueil
Accueil:
    path: /Accueil
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::accueil
HelloName:
    path: /hello-world/{name}
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::helloName
Reprog:
    path: /Reprog
    controller: App\Controller\ReprogController::reprog
NosVoitures:
    path: /NosVoitures
    controller: App\Controller\NosVoituresController::nosVoitures
Contact:
    path: /Contact
    controller: App\Controller\ContactController::contact
Services:
    path: /Services
    controller: App\Controller\ServicesController::services
```

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jw-motorsport.fr
    ServerAlias www.jw-motorsport.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jw-motorsport.fr/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/jw-motorposrt.fr/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/jw-motorsport.fr/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/jw-motorsport.fr/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If you need other src?

I have already clear my cache, repertory have 755 rights, and owner is not the root.

I have install apache-pack.

And when I display available route, I have:

```
[root@vps60891 html]# php bin/console debug:route
 ------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------
  Name          Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 ------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------
  Index         ANY      ANY      ANY    /
  Accueil       ANY      ANY      ANY    /Accueil
  HelloName     ANY      ANY      ANY    /hello-world/{name}
  Reprog        ANY      ANY      ANY    /Reprog
  NosVoitures   ANY      ANY      ANY    /NosVoitures
  Contact       ANY      ANY      ANY    /Contact
  Services      ANY      ANY      ANY    /Services
```

Request HTTP:

> [02/Feb/2020:09:18:37 -0500] "GET /Reprog HTTP/1.1" 404 204 "http://jw-motorsport.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"

Comment: Probably don't need the html in: /var/www/jw-motorsport.fr/html/public.  And your log should probably go to a tmp directory of some sort.  Might try setting up a very simple  one page index.html site just to get an idea of how Apache virtual hosts work.

Comment: Try other syntaxe change => controller: App\Controller\IndexController::accueil to => controller: AppBundle:Index:accueil

Comment: @Cerad : I dont undestand your idea ? I have already done a simple website when i have create my first virtual host and works fine.

Comment: @Julien Bald : This notation dont change anything, but thanks for your reply.

Comment: in your vhosts file you have: /var/www/jw-motorsport.fr/HTML/public Typically the public directory is directly under your project directory.  If you really added an html directory then great.  Just seems a bit strange.

Comment: @Cerad : Yes the root directory of my project is the HTML folder create by me. When you install http you have /var/www/html, and for have multisite, you need to create a repertory for each website into www repertory and configure vhost etc into available folders etc (i follow notice on web tuto for manage multisite). But you tell is ok but strange ? I dont understand if i make a mystake or not ?^^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it seems to be a problem with `.htaccess` file (if you don't have it). If you check the Symfony documentation about Apache [Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) it has an optimized configuration disabling `.htaccess`, try adapting your VirtualHost configuration like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld

DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
DirectoryIndex /index.php

<Directory /var/www/project/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    FallbackResource /index.php
</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
# <Directory /var/www/project>
#     Options FollowSymlinks
# </Directory>

# optionally disable the fallback resource for the asset directories
# which will allow Apache to return a 404 error when files are
# not found instead of passing the request to Symfony
<Directory /var/www/project/public/bundles>
    FallbackResource disabled
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

# optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
#SetEnv APP_ENV prod
#SetEnv APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>
#SetEnv DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name"
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have a .htaccess, but i try your idea and i have disable my .htaccess, but he doenst works, thanks for your reply !